# ImportError: No module named roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed ROS1 base version from source in the directory: `/home/mdc/ros_base/`.

To finish the installation, I executed `source /home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/setup.bash`.

Then I execute the command `printenv | grep 'ROS\|PYTHONPATH'` to check the environment variables of ROS and here is the output:

```
ROS_ROOT=/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/mdc/ros_base/src/ros_comm/rosbag:/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/share:/home/mdc/ros/install_isolated/share:/home/mdc/ros/src
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/mdc/ros_base/devel_isolated/rosbag/share/common-lisp:/home/mdc/ros/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
PYTHONPATH=/home/mdc/ros_base/devel_isolated/rosbag/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/mdc/ros/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ROS_ETC_DIR=/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/etc/ros
```

Also, I execute `which roslaunch` and get the output as below:

```
/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/bin/roslaunch
```

Now, my project is here: `/home/mdc/catkin_ws/`, so here is what I'm doing:

```
cd /home/mdc/catkin_ws
roslaunch ./src/mylaunch/launch/classic_mode.launch
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module>
        import roslaunch
    ImportError: No module named roslaunch
```

However, I checked the path: `/home/mdc/ros_base/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which has been set into `PYTHONPATH` as above and I saw there was a directory named `roslaunch`. I think this is exactly the module roslaunch, right? If so, why can't it find the module roslaunch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285128/importerror:-no-module-named-roslaunch/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

plz execute source /opt/ros/distro/setup.bash fristly

---

Originally posted by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) with karma: 46 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0